# PineScript Strategy Script Troubleshooting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I am new to PineScript, and I am trying to backtest a strategy that I created based off of some other scripts that were indicators. I believe I have written everything correctly, but when I go to compile, I get the error “Incorrect 'for' statement. Expecting 'to ’.” for the first for loop in the function `get_ob_price_level()` below. Would anyone mind helping me with this issue please? I’ve looked around stack overflow, and it seems that this error shows whenever there is any kind of syntax error in a for block. I’m just not sure what the error is. I’ve tried asking Codex and ChatGPT to find errors given the error statement, but it keeps giving me bogus answers like “function declarations only use => for one liners, multi line functions require {}”.
This portion of the code is supposed to search for nearby order blocks generated from previous code, then save and set price levels associated with those order blocks as sl and tp levels for any single trade. The code I used for order block generation was taken right from LuxAlgo’s SMC Indicator: https://www.tradingview.com/script/CnB3fSph-Smart-Money-Concepts-LuxAlgo/ Specifically lines 630-640 & 754-810.
Here is my code:

```
//@version=5
strategy('My Strategy'
  , overlay = true
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_bars_back = 500)

// Getting inputs
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
fast_length = input(title='MACD Fast Length', defval=12)
slow_length = input(title='MACD Slow Length', defval=26)
signal_length = input.int(title='MACD Signal Smoothing', minval=1, maxval=50, defval=9)
sma_source = input(title='Simple MA (Oscillator)', defval=false)
sma_signal = input(title='Simple MA (Signal Line)', defval=false)
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title='RSI Length')
rsi = ta.rsi(close, len)
longcondition = macd > signal and rsi < 30
shortcondition = macd < signal and rsi > 70
cc = longcondition and longcondition[1] == false ? color.green : shortcondition and shortcondition[1] == false ? color.red : color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
barcolor(cc)

//Timeframes
longcondition1W = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", longcondition)
shortcondition1W = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", shortcondition)
longcondition1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", longcondition)
shortcondition1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", shortcondition)
longcondition4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", longcondition)
shortcondition4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", shortcondition)
longcondition1H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", longcondition)
shortcondition1H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", shortcondition)
longcondition45Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "45", longcondition)
shortcondition45Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "45", shortcondition)
longcondition15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", longcondition)
shortcondition15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", shortcondition)

// Majority Calculation
var int condLong = 0
var int condShort = 0
var string TF = ""
if input.bool(true, "1W", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1W
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1WL"
    if shortcondition1W
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1WS"
    // 1D
if input.bool(true, "1D", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1D
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1DL"
    if shortcondition1D
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1DS"
    // 4H
if input.bool(true, "4H", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition4H
        condLong += 1
        TF += "4HL"
    if shortcondition4H
        condShort += 1
        TF += "4HS"
    // 1H
if input.bool(true, "1H", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition1H
        condLong += 1
        TF += "1HL"
    if shortcondition1H
        condShort += 1
        TF += "1HS"
    // 45Min
if input.bool(true, "45Min", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition45Min
        condLong += 1
        TF += "45MinL"
    if shortcondition45Min
        condShort += 1
        TF += "45MinS"
    // 15Min
if input.bool(true, "15Min", group = "Timeframes")
    if longcondition15Min
        condLong += 1
        TF += "15MinL"
    if shortcondition15Min
        condShort += 1
        TF += "15MinS"
longValOne = longcondition and longcondition[1]
longValTwo = condLong > condShort
shortValOne = shortcondition and shortcondition[1]
shortValTwo = condShort > condLong

ob_price_lvls = array.new_float(2)

get_ob_price_level() =>

    // get entry price level
    entry_price_level = strategy.position_avg_price 

    // get the order block closest to entry price against our direction
    for j = 0 to (bar_index - array.get(iob_left, 0)) //something inside this for block is wrong, possibly namespace
                                                      // or outdated method usage
      if array.get(iob_type, j) == -strategy.position_size // if the order block is against our position
        if strategy.position_size > 0 and array.get(iob_top, j) < entry_price_level // if long and order block top is below entry level
          array.set(ob_price_lvls, 0, array.get(iob_top, j))
        if strategy.position_size < 0 and array.get(iob_btm, j) > entry_price_level // if short and order block bottom is above entry level
          array.set(ob_price_lvls, sl_ob_price_level, array.get(iob_btm, j))

    // get the order block in our direction closest to double the difference between our entry price and sl_ob_price_level
    var float ob_dist = math.abs(array.get(ob_price_lvls, sl_ob_price_level) - entry_price_level) * 2
    for j = 0 to (bar_index - array.get(iob_left, 0))
      if array.get(iob_type, j) == strategy.position_size // if the order block is in our direction
        if strategy.position_size > 0 and array.get(iob_btm, j) > entry_price_level and array.get(iob_btm, j) - entry_price_level >= ob_dist // if long and order block bottom is above ob_price_level
          array.set(ob_price_lvls, 1, array.get(iob_btm, j))
        if strategy.position_size < 0 and array.get(iob_top, j) < entry_price_level and entry_price_level - array.get(iob_top, j) >= ob_dist // if short and order block top is below ob_price_level
          array.set(ob_price_lvls, tp_ob_price_level, array.get(iob_top, j))

// Alerts, Entry & Exit

bool longOrShort = na

alertOn = input(true, 'Alerts')
if longValOne and longValTwo and alertOn
  alert('New Long Signal - MACD/RSI', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
  strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1)
  longOrShort := true
  get_ob_price_level()
if shortValOne and shortValTwo and alertOn
  alert('New Short Signal - MACD/RSI', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
  strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1)
  longOrShort := false
  get_ob_price_level()
```

I tried playing with the indentation in the main function, I tried asking Codex and ChatGPT for suggestions, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to try more

> I tried playing with the indentation

As I see in this code, you have only two spaces for `if` and everything inside them, instead of four.
All local scopes must be separated by a multiple of 4 spaces.You have this problem both in the main code and in the function `get_ob_price_level()`

And in the future, please attach a code example that reproduces the problem and executes just as you describe.
Your snippet doesn't define many variables, script version, and type, which is why it generates completely different errors.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I fixed the spacing issue, but my problem still persists. I will edit my question to include more complete information so it can be understood better. I wonder if you have any suggestions for additional learning resources? I'm new to PineScript and don't really know where to go besides the Language Reference Manual and User Manual.

Comment: At line 109 of updated code you have six spaces for local scope, it isn't multiply of 4.
You should use 8 spaces for that scope, because it's local scope in another scope.